# How can the soul of a person return to its body if it was cremated?

Tags: death, soul

People like Hindus cremate dead bodies when they die. When the soul is supposed to return to their grave and body , what will happen to them because they don't have a body?

Comment: It will be injected back to the body, the same way it happened the first time.

Comment: But there is no body.

Comment: neither there was a body the first time. doing something you've done before is actually easier.

Comment: The baby when it is being made has a shape of a body and then the soul is out into it. So there was no body where?

Comment: Can you please rephrase: "So there was no body where?"

Comment: There's a hadith, possibly a weak one, about a man - I think he was a kafir in the hadith - who told his sons to burn his body after his death to escape judgement day. The hadith goes on to say that he was reassembled anyway - bodies decay after all, so they would have to be reconstituted one way or another - and that his fear  showed that he was in fact a believer, and was granted paradise for it. The relevant point here is: if you believe that a body that has decayed can be brought back, then why not a body that was burned?

Comment: For Allah, who made us from nothing, is much easier to make us again, while we will be in soil

Answer (score -2):

This is a very basic question which non-believers asked prophet, and even today they ask this.

This is strange a believer like you need to ask such thing, but its good that you asked.

Let me quote some verses form quran and than i will give you something for reading.

> وَيَقُولُ الإِْنْسَانُ أَءِذَا مَا مِتُّ لَسَوْفَ أُخْرَجُ حَيّاً *
>   أَوَلَا يَذْكُرُ الْإِنسَانُ أَنَّا خَلَقْنَاهُ مِن قَبْلُ وَلَمْ يَكُ
>   شَيْئاً 
> **And says man: What! when I am dead shall I truly be brought
>   forth alive? Does not man remember that We created him before, when he
>   was nothing?** (19:66-67)
>
> يُخْرِجُ الْحَىَّ مِنَ الْمَيِّتِ وَيُخْرِجُ الْمَيِّتَ مِنَ الْحَىِ‏ّ
>   وَيُحْىِ الْأَرْضَ بَعْدَ مَوْتِهَا وَكَذَ لِكَ تُخْرَجُونَ 
> **He
>   brings forth the living from the dead and brings forth the dead from
>   the living, and gives life to the earth after its death, and thus(in the same way)
>   shall you be brought forth.** (30:19)
>
> O people! if you are in doubt about the raising, then surely We
>   created you from dust, then from a small seed, then from a clot, then
>   from a lump of flesh, complete in make and incomplete, that We may
>   make clear to you; and We cause what We please to stay in the wombs
>   till an appointed time, then We bring you forth as babies, then that
>   you may attain your maturity; and of you is he who is caused to die,
>   and of you is he who is brought back to the worst part of life, so
>   that after having knowledge he does not know anything; and you see the
>   earth sterile land, but when We send down on it the water, it stirs
>   and swells and brings forth of every kind a beautiful herbage. This is
>   because Allah is the Truth and because He gives life to the dead and
>   because He has power over all things. And because the hour is coming,
>   there is no doubt about it; and because Allah shall raise up those who
>   are in the graves. (22:5-7)
>
> **And He it is Who originates the creation, then reproduces it, and it
>   is easy to Him**… (30:27)
>
> “**How can you disbelieve in Allaah? Seeing that you were dead and He
>   gave you life. Then He will give you death, then again will bring you
>   to life (on the Day of Resurrection) and then unto Him you will
>   return**”
>
> [al-Baqarah 2:28]

Now, after all these verses. It should be very clear that the same Allah who created you for the first time, its easier for him to bring you back to life.

Now, about reading, only reading i can suggest right now is a must read, its Quran with proper translation. Its just sad that muslims have left reading quran and understanding it. Its the message from Allah and we have left it. At least read whole quran translation from some authentic translation source in your own language.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question.

Comment: My question is about death and not the day of judgement. The soul comes out of your body when you die and after in the grave when the questions are asked your soul stay in the body in the grave. If someone was cremated or was eaten by an animal he won't have a body so where will his soul go?

Comment: @Armaan Are you trying to understand the exact process of attaching pieces of body together? If so I don't we know. But think about it, do you know how god bonds broken bones? (broken metals don't bond) Do you know how from a semen and eggs, something so tiny a giant human is made—with such characteristics?

Comment: @Armaan - Ok, i got you, you. I will update my answer accordingly.